# php-Facebook redirect after registration?

Tags: php, facebook

I am using the php sdk in order to login the users to the website. Also I am using the redirect_uri to redirect to login.php I am setting up a cookie with the user id. Then I am checking if the cookie exists I am using the header function in order to dircet the users back to main.php

```
<?php   if(isset($_COOKIE['id']) == false){

        require_once('scripts/facebook.php');
        $config = array('appId' => 'xxx','secret' => 'xxx');
        $params = array('scope' => 'email,offline_access,user_birthday', 'redirect_uri' => 'http://www.xxx.com/login.php');
        $facebook = new Facebook($config);
        $user = $facebook->getUser(); 

        if($user) {

            try {

            $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
        $userid = $user_profile['username'];



                //insert cookie
                $expire = time() + 31556926;
                $cookie_id = $user_profile['username'];
                setcookie("id", $cookie_id, $expire);
                header('Location: main.php');



          } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
                            $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
                            echo '<img src="assets/login.png"><br>';
                            echo '<a href="' . $login_url . '"><img src="assets/facebook_login.png"></a>';
                            error_log($e->getType());
                            error_log($e->getMessage());
          }   
        } else {

            $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
            echo '<img src="assets/login.png"><br>';
            echo '<a href="' . $login_url . '"><img src="assets/facebook_login.png"></a>';
        }//end facebook
        }else{
            //if cookie id is set
            header('Location: main.php');
            }
    ?>
```

now, the problem is when the user authenticated the app, it is redirecting to the login page. which means that the php page is not getting refreshed. How can I solve this problem ? 
UPDATE: if the user refresh the page or click login again he will be automatically redirected to main ?

Comment: Are you opening separate window to authenication?

Comment: No, it is using the same window.

Comment: Okay, then which php page does not refresh?

Comment: after the authentication, login.php should refresh and redirect the user to main.php. Login.php is not refreshing after the authentication, so it is not redirecting the user. The thing is when the user refresh the page or click login again it is sending him to main.php

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue here. I redirect the website user to login using the Facebook site via the Facebook PHP function getLoginURL(). Once a user has gone to login screen at Facebook and been redirected back to my site, the page does not refresh. This means that I cannot update the page display for the now currently logged-on user. This seems a bit daft - because I would have thought that would be the obvious 'default' thing to do.

If I/you add the client-side Facebook JS and root div, then the process works with a Facebook JS driven page reload - but this reload based on pulling in the client-side Facebook JS is a dependency I could do without - it just adds bloat and complicates things. Anyone with any other ideas on how to get around this.

The client-side JS is placed just before your closing body tag:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId: '<?php echo $facebook->getAppID() ?>',
      cookie: true,
      xfbml: true,
      oauth: true
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
      window.location.reload();
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
      window.location.reload();
    });
  };
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>
```